# Angular 2, how to access DOM element in index.html

Tags: html, google-maps, dom, angular, google-maps-markers

H, im trying to get access to the div element that I have created in the DOM (index.html) from my Angular 2 component.

What I what to accomplish:
Option 1:

1: Hide a div element when the page loads with jQuery.

2: Show that element again but inside on an Angular 2 component.

Problem with option 1:

I have no access to elements that have been created inside index.html from an Angular 2 component.

Option 2:

1: Load my **google maps script** when my maps component is loaded.

2: Created the **div googleMap** inside of my component instead.

Problmen with option 2:

I cannot/don't know how to load external Javascript from inside of an component.

You can tried the whole google maps API by just copy paste the HTML code and run that in a browser, or USE the Run Code snippet functions inside Stackoverflow.

Here is a minified version at plunker ! =>


## Plunker Version

Thanks for your patient all and just ask if something is unclear.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <base href='/'>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- You will need styles to show the map -->
    <style>
      #googleMap{
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid green;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- jQuery API -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Maps -->
    <!-- Marker cluster api to be able to add many pointers to google maps -->
    <script
      src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
    </script>

    <!-- Google maps UI -->
      <script
        async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRkoeyhWeokhDYDzGPJoBExYdVDi9FbzE&callback=initMap">
      </script>

    <!--
      This script loads from inside the URL 3 lines above this line
      to trigger and write out our map inside the googleMap div
    -->
    <script>
    function initMap() {

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: {lat: 57.715567, lng: 11.984026}
      });

      // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
      var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

      // Add some markers to the map.
      // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
      // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
      // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
      var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          label: labels[i % labels.length]
        });
      });

      // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
      var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
          {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
    }
    var locations = [
      /******
      **
      ** Sweden cordinates
      **
      ******/
      {lat: 57.683522, lng: 12.002759},
      {lat: 57.700674, lng: 11.974408},
      {lat: 57.681494, lng: 12.003012},
      {lat: 57.678302, lng: 12.005312},
      {lat: 57.656136, lng: 12.016982},
      {lat: 57.656122, lng: 12.019364},
      {lat: 57.649467, lng: 12.002159},
      {lat: 57.646449, lng: 11.996659},
      {lat: 57.641077, lng: 12.009796},
      {lat: 57.612011, lng: 11.929612},
      {lat: 57.709454, lng: 11.704358},
      {lat: 57.715483, lng: 11.782698},
      {lat: 57.716376, lng: 11.778341},
      {lat: 57.701065, lng: 11.913668},
      {lat: 57.701065, lng: 11.913668},
      {lat: 57.706186, lng: 11.937175},
      {lat: 57.707057, lng: 11.939428},
      {lat: 57.705784, lng: 11.941048},
      {lat: 57.705108, lng: 11.938044},
      {lat: 57.706579, lng: 11.936004},
      {lat: 57.705884, lng: 11.936366},
      {lat: 57.705522, lng: 11.939739},
      {lat: 57.713506, lng: 11.948909},
      {lat: 57.732862, lng: 11.955038},
      {lat: 57.788828, lng: 12.022301},
      {lat: 57.797326, lng: 12.051568},
      {lat: 57.739628, lng: 12.134029},
      {lat: 57.703938, lng: 11.967092},
      {lat: 57.705761, lng: 11.969560},
      {lat: 57.709389, lng: 11.967522}
    ];
    </script>

    <!-- Added hide and show buttons temporarly for testing DOM access -->
    <script defer>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          jQuery("#hide").click(function(){
              $("#googleMap").hide();
          });
          jQuery("#show").click(function(){
              $("#googleMap").show();
          });
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>

    <!-- Main app component -->
    <my-app>Main app Loading...</my-app>

      <!-- Google maps UI (temp location) -->
      <div #googleMapViewChild id="googleMap"></div>

      <button id="hide">Hide Map</button>
      <button id="show">Show Map</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

```js
import {  Component, OnInit, Renderer, ContentChild, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var componentHandler: any;
declare var jQuery:any;
   
@Component({
  selector: 'maps',
  template: `
     <!-- This is what I want to accomplish and load the map from 
          inside this component, but I dont know how to refresh or 
          load the external Javascript from an component. 
      -->
     <div id="googleMap"></div>
  ´,
  styleUrls: [
      'app/maps/maps.component.css'
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off not mixing angular2 with jQuery. Just put your map into your component and do it the angular way:

```js
@Componnet({
  selector: 'maps',
  template: '<div>
    <div #googleMapViewChild id="googleMap" *ngIf="visible"></div>
    <button (click)="visible=true">show</button>
    <button (click)="visible=false">hide</button>'
})
export class MapsComponent {
  visible: boolean = true;
}
```

Comment: Problem is that Angular can't find the google map API inside an Angular component so even if I make a div googleMap our google-maps.service.js script don't have any ide that there is a div in our component.

Comment: As soon as plunker is back up, I will show a demo there with all the Angular code aswell so people see the big picture and can understand the problem.

Comment: I have added a plunker version now.

Comment: Okay. The plunkr can help. Do you mean that the script can be run or that the `getElementById` fails (which is logical because you don't have the element yet)?